# Странное смещение дат в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, дата

Проблема 1: 
Одна и та же версия ноды, и там и там системное время задано правильно, временная зона Europe/Moscow с двух сторон, DST настроено правильно.
[image: Debian 9.4 stretch, x64 - Windows 10 Pro, x64]
Проблема 2: 
Дата на фронте преобразуется в UTC -> отправляется на сервер -> сохраняется в MySQL. Возвращается с сервера -> преобразуется в локальное время -> выводится.

В момент возврата с сервера старое доброе смещение на 1 час, а при преобразовании в локальное — на 1 день(!!!).

При этом, если бекэнд запущен под виндой(Windows 10 Pro, x64) — никакого смещения вообще нет, если под дебианом(Debian 9.4 stretch, x64) — 1 час -> 1 день

Из-за чего может возникать подобная ошибка?

Фронтэнд (вырезано все то, что с ней не связано):
Используется JQuery 3.3.1 и Vue 2.5.13
Используется заголовок

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Получение:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/sns/getAccount",
    data: { id: id },
    success: function (result) {
        profileUI.vue.account = result;

        if (result.birthDate)
            Vue.nextTick(function () {
                if (!profileUI.birthDatePicker)
                    profileUI.birthDatePicker = $('#profileUI .editProfileContainer input.birthDateInput.datepicker-here').datepicker({
                        toggleSelected: false,
                        onSelect: function (formattedDate, date, inst) {
                            profileUI.vue.account.birthDate = date.toISOString();
                        }
                    }).data('datepicker');

                profileUI.birthDatePicker.selectDate(birthDate);
            })
    }
});
```

Отправка:

```
profileUI.saveProfile = function () {
    var account = profileUI.vue.account;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/sns/editAccount',
            type: 'post',
            data: profileUI.vue.account,
            success: function (result) {
                switchSubWindow('#profileUI', '.profileInfoContainer');
                profileUI.loadAccount(account.id);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
}
```

Бекэнд(вырезано все, что не связано с датой)
Используются пакеты NodeJS 9.11.1, express 4.16.2 и mysql 2.15.0
MySQL Community Server(в обоих случаях один и тот же, запущен на машине с дебианом(см выше))

Сохранение в БД:

```
router.post('/editAccount', (req, res) => {
                        connectionPool.query(sql.editAccountSQL,
                            req.body.birthDate?new Date(req.body.birthDate):null,
                            req.body.id],
                            err => {
                                if (!err) replyOk(res);
                                else replyError(res, err, 500);
                            });
})
```

Получение из БД:

```
queryDbAuthSensitive(req.cookies.token, sql.getAccountByIdSQL, [req.query.id], (err, rows) => {
                    replyOk(res, rows[0]);
        });
```

replyOk:

```
export function replyOk(res: Response, data: any = null) {
  if (!res.headersSent) res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(data ? JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) : '{}');
}
```

sql.getAccountByIdSQL =

```
SELECT * FROM Account WHERE id = ? LIMIT 2;
```

sql.editAccount =

```
UPDATE Account
SET birthDate = ?
WHERE id = ?;
```

Comment: В чем вопрос? И приведите исходный код по своему вопросу.

Comment: Судя по скриншоту в какой-то ОСи неправильная tzdata про 1997 год

Comment: Обновил до последней версии(2018c) -- то же самое

Comment: Спасибо, понял, дело в tzdata. Осталось разобраться, как заставить nodejs ее использовать. Но это уже дело времени.

Comment: Каламбур получился)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все или большинство приложений используют дату сервера по-умолчанию, но можно переопределить `timezone` например для `php` или `mysql` и других. UTC позволяет хранить дату в универсальном формате и затем переводить её в локальное время пользователя, приложения. Это важно если данные вашего приложения используются/модифицируются пользователями из разных временных зон.

Если приложение гарантированно используется в одной временной зоне, то нужно "выровнять", то есть правильно настроить ваше приложение и все сервера, которые оно использует. И никаких смещений не будет.

Да, проблема есть для отдельных временных зон, например:

- время в UTC 20:34, дата 2018-01-31
- локальная зона +4
- прибавляем 20:34+4 и получаем 00:34 следующего дня - 2018-02-01

Если все даты в одной зоне, никаких проблем не будет. Если нужно использовать разные зоны, то дату нужно хранить в UTC. UTC позволит "легко переводить" время в разные временные зоны.

Итак

- нужно правильно настроить все серверы, библиотеки (если нужно)
- чётко определить потребности приложения (локальные или международные потребители)
- использовать библиотеки для манипуляции датой, например [moment](https://momentjs.com/)
- определить формат хранения даты/времени (UTC,...)
- учитывать локальное время при запросах к базе данных (если нужно)
- добавить возможность выбора временной зоны для пользователя, приложения

p.s. Это некоторые заметки о работе. Никакого "странного смещения" в node.js нет, работа с датой требует внимания и понимая целей приложения, правильной настройки окружения, также как и в других средах. Например если сервер баз данных размещен не на том же сервере, что и приложение, то неправильная настройка временных зон может привести к неправильной работе приложения.

Answer (score -1):

Костыль, достаточно прочный, чтобы временно решить проблему:

Время по UTC получается на 1 день раньше нашего. 
Собственно, вырезал все дальше T(т.к. для даты рождения просто не нужно) -> распарсил как наше -> +1 день.

```
var birthDate = new Date(result.birthDate.split('T')[0]);
birthDate.setDate(birthDate.getDate()+1);
```

Внимание! Гарантированно работает только по Москве. Меня это пока устраивает. Для других временных зон - на свой страх и риск.